# integral solutions to system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Let $A$ be a $n$ by $n+m$ matrix in integers. We suppose that the first $n$ columns form $d I_n$ where $I_n$ is the identity matrix and nonzero $d \in \mathbb{Z}$. We also suppose that the greatest common divisor of all the determinants of $n$ by $n$ submatrices of $A$ is $1$.

With the usual method in linear algebra we can obtain that every solution to $A x = 0$ can be expressed, by clearing out denominators if necessary, as a linear combination of $v_1, ..., v_m \in \mathbb{Z}^{n + m}$.

What I am struggling to show is that how can I prove that if
$$
c_1 v_1 + ... + c_m v_m \in \mathbb{Z}^{m + n}
$$
then each $c_i \in \mathbb{Z}$? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have other assumptions on the vectors $v_i$'s?

Comment: not in the question, but if it's necessary would like to know!

Comment: But how do you know that the solutions can be expressed as a linear combination of vectors in $\mathbb{Z}$. That might not the be the case. Did you find those vectors?

Comment: Since all the entries of $A$ are integers, in particular rational numbers. so we can do linear algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ and get $v_1,,, v_m$ as vectors in $\mathbb{Q}$. Then we can multiply each vector by a suitable integer to clear the denominators

Comment: Yes I did that in the meantime and got explicit solutions. I am now doing the rest of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

It is immediate to see that the null-space of $A=:\left[dI_n\ M\right]$, $M\in\mathbb{Z}^{n\times m}$, has dimension $m$. In this case, all solutions $x$ such that $Ax=0$ can be written as

$$x=\begin{bmatrix}-M\\dI_m\end{bmatrix}y,\ y\in\mathbb{Z}^m.$$

One can pick, for instance, the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ to be

$$v_i=\begin{bmatrix}-M\\dI_m\end{bmatrix}e_i,\ i=1,\ldots,m$$

where $\{e_1,\ldots,e_m\}$ is the natural basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$.

For the implication, we prove that if some $c_i$'s are in $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ then $L(c)=c_1 v_1 + ... + c_m v_m \notin \mathbb{Z}^{m + n}$ (or not in $\mathbb{Q}^{m + n}$).

If only $c_1$ is in $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$, then we have $c_1v_1=-(c_2v_2+\ldots+c_mv_m)$ where the left hand side is irrational and the right hand side is irrational. This cannot be and we get a contradiction.

If $c_1$ and $c_2$ are in $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$, then we have $c_1v_1+c_2v_2=-(c_3v_3+\ldots+c_mv_m)$. What can happen here is that the irrational terms cancel each other on the left hand side to yield a rational. But that it not possible as $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent.

The general case follows from the same arguments.

This proves that if $c_1 v_1 + ... + c_m v_m \in \mathbb{Z}^{m + n}$, then we have that all the $c_i$'s are in $\mathbb{Q}$.

If one wants to have the same statement for $\mathbb{Z}$, I would suspect that more assumptions, for instance on $M$, are needed. Still thinking about it.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. but it seems that it only explains why each $c_i$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$, but not in $\mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: @JohnnyT. The argument is the same.

Comment: suppose $v_1 = (1, -3, 2, 0)$ and $v_2 = (-1, 3, 0, 2)$. then $\frac12 v_1 + \frac12 v_2 = (0,0,1,1)$. how does your argument rule out something like this?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Without more assumptions (for instance on MMM), I guess, one cannot rule out this case. I have updated my answer accordingly. Note that your case could not happen should the vectors $v_i$'s be orthogonal but for that we would need extra assumptions on $M$. Another, option would be to assume that $M$ is full rank.

Comment: I'm starting to think that maybe there are counter examples to my question as written...

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean. Your vectors orthogonal but that does not solve anything. Also, if $M$ is full rank then those vector cannot exist.